# Emacs functions to read user input

Tags: emacs

I need functions to ask for user input both in: 1) Graphical and 2) non-Graphical environment in emacs.

found that I can do something like this for the non-graphical case:

```
(defun query-friends-phone (name)
  "…"
  (interactive "sEnter friend's name: ")
  (message "Name: %s" name)
)
```

I need an input box for the Graphical case. Something like an input box to ask for something like other languages. Does Emacs have such a thing?

(to avoid confusion something like this image: http://eleganceit.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/input-form.png, this is just the idea and I know it won't be like this!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs stays away from that approach. All the text is made to be entered in the main frame. You can have dialog boxes for questions that can be answered by clicking with a mouse (see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frames.html#Frames).

The GPG interface in emacs is using the approach you are suggesting for security purposes only. Having a separate window that captures all the keys no matter what makes sure that you do not accidentaly type your password in a file and save it to disk.